# How to pass textfield string to next view with the same class file?

Tags: ios, ios6

I am using same class files for different nib files. in the first nib file am getting user informations using text fields, and now i need those informations from the textfields in first nib file in the second nib. How can i get those?

Answer (score 0):

If they have a shared parent, you can access one from the other using `self.parentViewController.childViewControllers`. I'm not sure if this is necessarily best practice, though.

It seems like there wouldn't be a good reason to have two different views use the same class, though. Could you elaborate on why you are doing that?

Comment: i got a user registration form, for that i am using one registrationviewcontroller class and then views are username password input view and a set of 4 questionnaire views. all are using same class.

Comment: Well if I'm understanding you correctly, you should be doing everything in your `registrationviewcontroller` class. If you're brand new to iOS programming, any Hello World type tutorial will cover this.

Comment: while navigating to different views using same controller its not easy as we think, when u move to each view the textfield value becomes null. nsuser defaults solved my problem. Thanks Anthony. By the way am not a new user, am working more than one year on iOS. I got 2 apps in appstore.